# Hi, I am trying to build a simple calculator (just adds) in Spyder using python. How do I define end so that it will delete the previous number?

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Simple Calculator")

e= tk.Entry(root,width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

#define button_click
def button_click(number):
   
         e.delete(0,END) 
   
         e.insert(0,number)
    
#Define Buttons

button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command= lambda: button_click(1))

button_2 = tk.Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command= lambda: button_click(2))

button_3 = tk.Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))

button_4 = tk.Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))

button_5 = tk.Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))

button_6 = tk.Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))

button_7 = tk.Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))

button_8 = tk.Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))

button_9 = tk.Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))

button_0 = tk.Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))

button_add = tk.Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())

button_equal = tk.Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())

button_clear = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click())

# Put the buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)

button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)

button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)

button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should be  :#define button_click           New line:  def button_click(number):

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What previous number are you talking about? There is no previous number.

Comment: Ahh... I mean when I enter a number into the calculator, I want that number to be deleted as soon as I put another number in. For example, I press 7. I want 7 to be entered into the entry. When I then press 8, I want the 7 to be deleted so that 8 will take its place. The program however will not get past the "e.delete(0,END)" and the error is END is not defined.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. I had to add tk. before END ("e.delete(0,tk.END).  I do not exactly know why? Can someone maybe explain why I needed to do this step.

Comment: I had already answered that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
def button_click(number):
         e.delete(0, tk.END)  # tk.END instead of END
         e.insert(0,number)
```

This is because you've used

```
import tkinter as tk
```

which means that all functions that are inside tkinter are stored in the `tk` variable.